# What is this annoying popup when I try to edit text:

Tags: macos, text

Recently in some apps when I select a word to edit it, I sometimes (not always) get this annoying popup:

[image]

Once this popup appears, I cannot edit the text selected, and have to click away from it and start again. Where does this come from, and can I suppress it?

The exact behaviour is: I select text by sweeping with the mouse. Then I move the cursor back into the selected text without touching any mouse button. As soon as the cursor is in the selection and before I can click a button, the popup appears. The same thing happens using my trackpad

Answer (score 2):

This appears to be coming from the productivity app [Things 3](https://apps.apple.com/us/app/things-3/id904280696?mt=12).  You may have this in your login items (*Settings → Users & Groups → User → Login Items*).  Disable it there to prevent it from automatically starting.

Their support site has a great deal of info on how to use the product, but I was unable to find anything on preferences/settings.  There should be something in their settings that enables/disables actions when you select text.

If you have further difficulty, you may wish to contact that developer directly through their website: https://culturedcode.com/things/support/

Comment: Doesn‘t this look like the standard context popup one also gets in Finder, with Things being one of the registered services?

Comment: Things isn't in my Login Items. This popup appears even when Things isn't running.

Comment: To get the standard contextual popup as @nohillside describes, you've got to right-click (or control-click) the text.  Are you saying that simply selecting the text does this action?  To see if it's a 3rd party app, boot into [Safe Mode](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201262) (Hold `Shift` while booting).  See if the problem persists.

Comment: Might be a partially sticky control key (or mouse key)triggering the menu.

Comment: That could be it @nohillside - Safe Mode will confirm because the symptom will exist there too.

Comment: OK, I booted into Safe mode and it's still happening. The exact behaviour is: I select text by sweeping with the mouse. Then I move the cursor back into the selected text without touching any mouse button. As soon as the cursor is in the selection and before I can click a button, the popup appears. The same thing happens using my trackpad.

Comment: That doesn't exactly sound like a sticky (Control) key so, my answer (now) is incorrect, but I'll leave it here for the time being for the comments.  Post those symptoms to the question in case the comments get cleared.

Comment: I'm not familiar with this app but it sounds like it may have installed a daemon that causes this issue. Check your /Library/LaunchAgents & /Library/LaunchDaemons folders to see if any files are there with "Things" in their name & delete them then restart & see if that solves the issue. Just be aware that this may break Things.